# why EUXDT React Data grid is getting scattered in my project from flexicious?

Tags: flexicious

I am suing react 16. Is it possible work with react 16?
[Here is what happened when I implemented the grid in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j38eI.png)

I tried to change styles and other stuffs but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you are missing the styles import:

https://reactdatagrid.com/docs/intro

```
import "@ezgrid/grid-core/styles.css"
import "@ezgrid/grid-core/icons.css"
```